# Flashcards with textfraction

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\newcommand{\textfrac}[2]{
\frac{\text{#1}}{\text{#2}}
}
\begin{document}

$\textfrac{Verkehrsleistung tkm}{Gütermenge t}$

$\textfrac{Outputrate \times Rüstzeit}{1 - Outputrate \times Zeit pro       Stück}$

\end{document}
```

The first textfraction (and dozen others) works like a charm. The second one throws an error and I have no idea why. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\times` is a math symbol, hence your line should read

```
$\textfrac{Outputrate \(\times\) Rüstzeit}{1 - Outputrate \(\times\) Zeit pro       Stück}$
```

(or even in `$\times$` if you prefer). Then it works fine. This is of course, because inside `\text{...}` you are back to textmode and have to - interally - change to math mode again.

Comment: Thanks, working perfectly now. I will file this under "too easy to spot".